# JavaScript: Create a function that returns the frequency distribution of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, count

I am trying to create a function that returns the frequency distribution of an array. This function should return an object, where the keys are the unique elements and the values are the frequency in which those elements occur.

My code is below:

```
function getFrequencies(arr) {

  let obj = {}; 

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    let element = arr[i]; 

    console.log(element)

    // check if key exists in object already

    // if it exists, add 1 to the value
    if (obj[element] !== undefined){
      obj[element] += 1;
    }

    // if it does not exist, add 1 to setup future elements
    else {
      obj[element] === 1; 
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

getFrequencies(["A", "B", "A", "A", "A"])

My code returns: {} when it should return:

```
{ A: 4, B: 1 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're looking for `obj[element] = 1`. Assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else part is having equality instead of assignment

```
obj[element] === 1;
```

it should be

```
obj[element] = 1;
```

so your code actually never initialize any key on `obj`

```js
function getFrequencies(arr) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let element = arr[i];
    if (obj[element] !== undefined) {
      obj[element] += 1;
      console.log(obj, 'in if')
    }
    else {
      obj[element] === 1;
      console.log(obj, 'in else')
    }
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(getFrequencies(["A", "B", "A", "A", "A"]));
```

You can simply use `reduce`

```js
function getFrequencies(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((op, inp) => {
    op[inp] = op[inp] || 0
    op[inp]++
    return op
  },{})
}

console.log(getFrequencies(["A", "B", "A", "A", "A"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj[element] === 1;` this is the comparison operator, not assignment.

You want `obj[element] = 1;`

You can do this easier in ES6+, for what it's worth:

```
arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item] = (acc[item] || 0) + 1
  return acc
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` block, you are using strict comparison when it should simply be assignment, i.e.:

```
obj[element] = 1;
```

and *not*:

```
obj[element] === 1;
```

See working example below:

```js
function getFrequencies(arr) {

  let obj = {}; 

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    let element = arr[i]; 

    console.log(element)

    // check if key exists in object already

    // if it exists, add 1 to the value
    if (obj[element] !== undefined){
      obj[element] += 1;
    }

    // if it does not exist, add 1 to setup future elements
    else {
      obj[element] = 1; 
    }
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(getFrequencies(["A", "B", "A", "A", "A"]));
```